# RL Environment - OpenAI Gym Taxi-v2 vs Taxi-v3

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Gym Taxi-v2 is deprecated. My implementation of Q-learning still works with Taxi-v3 but for some reason, env.render() shows the wrong taxi position at each step.

Anyway, apart from an added wall, what are the differences between Taxi-v2 v Taxi-v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were small corrections in the description and in the map, you can look at the [pull request in github](https://github.com/openai/gym/pull/1653/files) for the details.